# Leave One Site Outの使い方

Tags: python, 機械学習

一体どのように使えばいいのでしょう？

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import LeaveOneOut
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneGroupOut
```

というようにインポートしたいのですが、ネット上でいくら探してもそれらしい記事が見つからず、お力をお借りしたいです

Comment: `import` 自体ができない（エラーが出る）ということでしょうか？

Comment: ドキュメントはこちらではないでしょうか - http://scikit-learn.org/stable/documentation.html

Answer (score 1):

次のようにインポートするのではないでしょうか。

```
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneGroupOut
```

ドキュメント
・[LeaveOneOut](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneOut.html)
・[LeaveOneGroupOut](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneGroupOut.html)